# What is the c# class StreamContent?

Tags: c#

This is probably explained somewhere on the web but I cant find it. What exactly is a StreamContent?

(I'm trying to understand C# but I cant properly understand some WebAPi examples cos I dont understand what a StreamContent is.

A link that fully explains it (and not just list its properties etc like MSDN) would be fine.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your search. StreamContent is the Content of a Stream, look for Stream.

Comment: @Gallen. I'm confused. I'm referrign to this class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.streamcontent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: From MSDN: `Provides HTTP content based on a stream.` Seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Matt Burland, This is just a quote from MSDN. Doesnt really explain it to me. E.g Why cant I just use a normal stream. Or why cant I just send a string when I want to return contetn? What does it do that makes it special for HTTP content? Why do not all examples of returning content from an HTTP request use it?

Comment: Perhaps the parent namespace will provide more context: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 21):

This is an old post, but came across it so perhaps it may help others: `StreamContent` is a content type that can be used to set the `.Content` property on a `HttpResponseMessage`.  This indicates to the web process that the content is to be streamed from a source stream (a readable stream) to the client.  For example, you could open a `FileStream` and pass it to the constructor of StreamContent, then set that onto the `.Content` property.  This will tell the server to read from the `FileStream` and stream the content down to the client, chunk by chunk.  This is often preferred vs. reading the (potentially large) source stream (the file) into ram first and then returning an array (in which case the web server must use RAM to hold the file and feed it down to the client).