# What exactly is the purpose of StreamContent? Can I use it to buffer ReadAsStreamAsync()?

Tags: c#, .net-core, networking, streaming

I've been trying to find a proper use context and purpose for Streamcontent, but haven't been able to find anything useful online. Can I use this to wrap a `ReadAsStreamAsync()` so I can add a buffer to it like so:

```
var streamToRead = new StreamContent(await message.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), 4096)
```

Comment: What data type is `message`? It looks like a Flurl response but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the c# class StreamContent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560675/what-is-the-c-sharp-class-streamcontent)

Comment: Consider the original (pre-TAP) usage might result in usages more like `new StreamContent(File.Open(..))` — then there is no intermediate copy of the data created.

Comment: @gunr2171 message is a HTTPResponseMessage and yes thank you, it explains it much better. So I'm guessing I can't use it in the way I was thinking about? It's more for uploading than downloading?